# Can't deploy contract, does not recognize my 1 ETH

Tags: wallets, ether, accounts, contract-deployment

The console says:

> We can't estimate your gas usage properly, because you need at least 1 ether in your account

Select fee is frozen. There is one ether listed at the top of the console.

Comment: This is likely due to the fact that you are not properly synced. Are you up to date with the sync?

Comment: I have moved on. this post is irrelevant now. Please stop with the negative flags. deleted by 5chdn♦ 11 hours ago
Why was your post deleted? See the help center. The post was deleted because I am no longer using ethereum.

Comment: The post was deleted because it was no answer. Please use the comments for additional information.